# Neovim lua module not found even though it exist

Tags: neovim, lua

I have structured my neovim config files like this

```bash
~/.config/nvim
├── init.lua
└── lua
    └── [username]
        ├── core
        │   └── options.lua
        ├── init.lua
        └── plugins
```

These are the contents of my files

```lua
-- init.lua

require("[username]")
```

```lua
-- ./lua/[username]/init.lua

print("hello world")
require("core.options")
```

```lua
-- ./lua/[username]/core/options.lua

local opt = vim.opt -- aliasing

-- line number
opt.number = true

-- tabs & intendation
opt.tabstop = 4
opt.shiftwidth = 4
opt.expandtab = true
opt.autoindent = true

-- search
opt.ignorecase = true
opt.smartcase = true

-- appearance
opt.termguicolors = false
opt.background = "dark"
```

When I open neovim, I get this error

```
hello world
Error detected while processing /home/[username]/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/[username]/.config/nvim/lua/[username]/init.lua:2: module 'core.options' not found:
        no field package.preload['core.options']
        no file './core/options.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/core/options.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/core/options.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/core/options/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/core/options.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/core/options/init.lua'
        no file './core/options.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/core/options.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/core/options.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
        no file './core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/core.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/[username]/.config/nvim/lua/[username]/init.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/[username]/.config/nvim/init.lua:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: I did find a solution, seems like every require call in lua/neovim starts from the lua directory. So changed `core.options` to `[username].core.options`.

Comment: Exactly. I just wanna point out that this is how Lua works, Neovim doesn't deviate from it

Comment: @me.nkr please post answers down below in the "Answers" section, not in comments.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I would like to but I still have not idea why that works, If anyone knows why that does, it would be a better answer I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change `core.options` to `[username].core.options`, since every `require` call in Lua looks for the file from the ***lua/*** directory.

The reason is not completely clear to me yet. But a simple reason would be, as @Tae said in comments,

> This is how Lua works.

I believe documentation of [Lua require function](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) can shed some light.

If someone can explain it better, please do.